# js: trigger a timing event after pause/resume

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger some event after a specific time. And the timer should be pausable.
Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xsH8v/

The problem is that How can I trigger this

```
  if (Clock.totalSeconds >= givenTime){
    alert('time is up!');
  }
```

I put it in the `document.ready`. But it does not get fired when the time is up. I think the problem is that the function does not get called at all. If this is so, how can I trigger it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method does not work because the if statement is only evaluated once; at document load. To fix that, you need to add callbacks which are checked every time the totalSeconds is updated.

Here's my solution; [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WWWaf/1/)

You can add functions using `Clock.at(time, callback)`, like so:

Clock.at(10, function() { /* 10 seconds passed */});

```
var Clock = {
    totalSeconds: 0,

    handlers: [],

    start: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.totalSeconds += 1;

            sec = parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60)
            min = Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60)
            hour = Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 3600)

            $("#hour").text(hour);
            $("#min").text(min);
            $("#sec").text(sec);

            // Fire each expired handlers
            self.handlers = self.handlers.filter(function(handler) {

                if (self.totalSeconds >= handler.time) {
                    // Fire the handler then remove it
                    handler.func();
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            })

        }, 1000);
    },

    pause: function () {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        delete this.interval;
    },

    resume: function () {
        if (!this.interval) this.start();
    },

    at: function(time, handler) {

        // Handle expired handlers
        if (this.totalSeconds >= time) handler();

        // Add the handler to the queue
        this.handlers.push({
            time: time,
            func: handler,
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the callback function `maxTime` to `Clock.start()` which will be exucted after extend the given time

```
var givenTime = 5;
//maxTime is call back function which is executed after extend giventTime
Clock.start(maxTime, givenTime);

function maxTime(){
   //do stuff after extend maximum time.
}

//here is your call back function is invoked when `givenTime` time is extended
// inside the `start function`
//after that every second the call back function is executed.

if(self.totalSeconds >= givenTime){
     callBack();
}
```

Here is complete [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xsH8v/1/)

If you want do execute timeup code only once. then you can set codnition inside `start()` function, like

```
if(self.totalSeconds == givenTime){
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/xsH8v/4/)

**UPDATE**

In your case, please make variable `giventTime` global by removing var, and place the `maxTime()` function from outside of the `$( document ).ready`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {...});

function maxTime(){
       alert('time up');
    }
```

And pass the relative parameters with `start()` function into `resume()` function, like

```
if (!this.interval) this.start(maxTime, givenTime)
```

[**DEMO3**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsH8v/8/)

Comment: You solution will call the callback every second after this first call, and will only allow one callback. I assume this is undesirable for OP

Comment: An additional question: In the `resume` function, arguments should be left empty?`if (!this.interval) this.start();`

Comment: I'm reall sorry, lndy's answer is really better. We could all learn something from his answer. His design approach is great.

Answer (score 0):

If statement should be called each time `totalSeconds` is updated by `setInterval` so put it inside the `setInterval` function. You can pass the given time to the start function as argument.
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsH8v/7/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  Clock.start(5);
  $('#pauseButton').click(function () { Clock.pause(); });
  $('#resumeButton').click(function () { Clock.resume(); });

});

var Clock = {
    totalSeconds: 0,

    start: function (maxTime) {
        var self = this;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.totalSeconds += 1;

            sec = parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60)
            min = Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60)
            hour = Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 3600)

            $("#hour").text(hour);
            $("#min").text(min);
            $("#sec").text(sec);

            // Check condition after each increment in Clock.totalSeconds
            if (Clock.totalSeconds >= maxTime) {
                Clock.pause();
                alert('time is up!');
            }
        }, 1000);
    },

    pause: function () {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        delete this.interval;
    },

    resume: function () {
        if (!this.interval) this.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: You solution will call the callback every second after this first call, which I assume is undesirable behaviour for OP.

Comment: I updated the solution, now it won't call the callback every second after this first call.